# Wierd traceroute / ICMP issues on Juniper SRX 210BE

Tags: juniper, networking, icmp, srx

I recently acquired Juniper SRX 210BE; until now I've been using Cisco ASA 5505 but I really want to switch over to Juniper world (big FreeBSD fan and all that).

I've got FTTC (fiber to the cabnet) internet feed that goes into a modem that changes the VDSL signal into ethernet and then from modem I connect Juniper with Ethernet cable and perform PPPoE auth on the Juniper.

Everything is working fine, but... I'm getting a major packet-loss according to both ping and traceroute.  The really weird thing is that it seems like this PL is only on ICMP / traceroute messages and it's not permanent but rather intermittent.  Eg. I'm going to get 10 packets lost then it's going to be fine for ~ 40 seconds and then another burst of PL.

The PL includes the first hop which is the Juniper itself!  Please see below.

```
Host                                                          Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 10.17.17.62                                                29.3%   454    1.3   1.5   0.9  21.6   1.7
 2. 109.224.191.50                                             13.2%   453   14.8  17.3  14.5 111.8   9.0
 3. 149.6.9.170                                                12.8%   453   15.3  18.5  14.5 149.1  13.2
 4. gi8-10.mag01.lhr01.atlas.cogentco.com                      13.7%   453   15.4  25.8  14.6 218.9  33.1
 5. te0-5-0-5.rcr21.lhr01.atlas.cogentco.com                   12.6%   453   16.3  17.5  15.0  69.7   6.5
 6. be2040.ccr41.lon13.atlas.cogentco.com                      13.5%   453   16.7  17.9  16.0  72.4   4.9
 7. be2194.ccr41.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com                      12.6%   453   23.9  25.8  23.4  74.6   6.1
 8. be2186.ccr41.ham01.atlas.cogentco.com                      12.8%   453   33.7  35.6  32.5  94.6   8.3
 9. be2147.rcr21.ber01.atlas.cogentco.com                      13.7%   453   36.9  39.8  36.2 104.3   9.1
10. te3-1.ccr01.poz01.atlas.cogentco.com                       13.2%   453   41.1  58.7  40.4 251.0  41.1
11. 149.6.28.22                                                13.2%   453   48.8  52.0  46.8 126.8   9.9
12. 81.210.127.195                                             13.5%   453   55.7  57.6  53.0 110.2   8.4
13. 83.238.250.131                                             38.9%   453   52.6  54.4  51.7  98.0   5.8
14. GdynR005RT01-RedaR001RT01.inetia.pl                        17.9%   453   53.5  54.8  52.4  93.4   5.9
15. ???
16. rtr4.rtr-int-1.adm.wp-sa.pl                                13.7%   453   55.5  57.3  54.7 120.9   6.8
17. www.wp.pl                                                  13.5%   453   55.3  56.8  54.5 111.9   6.3
```

10.17.17.62 is Juniper's internal IP -- how weird, isn't it?  The config is pretty much stock one with PPPoE auth configured as well as NAT.  See below:

```
## Last commit: 2014-10-17 23:19:14 BST by root
version 12.1X44-D40.2;
system {
    time-zone Europe/London;
    root-authentication {
        encrypted-password "xxx"; ## SECRET-DATA
    }
    name-server {
        208.67.222.222;
        208.67.220.220;
    }
    services {
        ssh;
        telnet;
        xnm-clear-text;
        web-management {
            http {
                interface vlan.16;
            }
            https {
                system-generated-certificate;
                interface vlan.16;
            }
        }
        dhcp {
            domain-name lon.domain;
            pool 10.17.17.0/26 {
                address-range low 10.17.17.32 high 10.17.17.55;
                default-lease-time 7200;
                name-server {
                    8.8.8.8;
                    8.8.4.4;
                }
                router {
                    10.17.17.62;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    syslog {
        archive size 100k files 3;
        user * {
            any emergency;
        }
        file messages {
            any critical;
            authorization info;
        }
        file interactive-commands {
            interactive-commands error;
        }
    }
    max-configurations-on-flash 5;
    max-configuration-rollbacks 5;
    license {
        autoupdate {
            url https://ae1.juniper.net/junos/key_retrieval;
        }
    }
}
interfaces {
    interface-range interfaces-trust {
        member ge-0/0/1;
        member fe-0/0/3;
        member fe-0/0/4;
        member fe-0/0/5;
        member fe-0/0/6;
        member ge-0/0/0;
        member fe-0/0/2;
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fe-0/0/2 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fe-0/0/3 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fe-0/0/4 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fe-0/0/5 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fe-0/0/6 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members vlan-trust;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fe-0/0/7 {
        unit 0 {
            encapsulation ppp-over-ether;
        }
    }
    pp0 {
        traceoptions {
            flag all;
        }
        unit 0 {
            point-to-point;
            ppp-options {
                chap {
                    default-chap-secret "xxx"; ## SECRET-DATA
                    local-name "xxx";
                    passive;
                }
            }
            pppoe-options {
                underlying-interface fe-0/0/7.0;
                idle-timeout 0;
                auto-reconnect 30;
                client;
            }
            no-keepalives;
            family inet {
                negotiate-address;
            }
        }
    }
    vlan {
        unit 16 {
            family inet {
                address 10.17.17.62/26;
            }
        }
    }
}
routing-options {
    static {
        route 0.0.0.0/0 {
            next-hop pp0.0;
            metric 0;
        }
    }
}
protocols {
    stp {
        disable;
        interface ge-0/0/0.0 {
            disable;
        }
        interface ge-0/0/1.0 {
            disable;
        }
        interface fe-0/0/2.0 {
            disable;
        }
        interface fe-0/0/3.0 {
            disable;
        }
        interface fe-0/0/4.0 {
            disable;
        }
        interface fe-0/0/5.0 {
            disable;
        }
        interface fe-0/0/6.0 {
            disable;
        }
    }
}
security {
    flow {
        tcp-mss {
            all-tcp {
                mss 1380;
            }
        }
    }
    screen {
        ids-option untrust-screen {
            ip {
                source-route-option;
                tear-drop;
            }
            tcp {
                syn-flood {
                    alarm-threshold 1024;
                    attack-threshold 200;
                    source-threshold 1024;
                    destination-threshold 2048;
                    timeout 20;
                }
                land;
            }
        }
    }
    nat {
        source {
            rule-set trust-to-untrust {
                from zone trust;
                to zone untrust;
                rule source-nat-rule {
                    match {
                        source-address 10.17.17.0/26;
                    }
                    then {
                        source-nat {
                            interface;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    policies {
        from-zone trust to-zone untrust {
            policy trust-to-untrust {
                match {
                    source-address any;
                    destination-address any;
                    application any;
                }
                then {
                    permit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    zones {
        security-zone trust {
            host-inbound-traffic {
                system-services {
                    all;
                }
                protocols {
                    all;
                }
            }
            interfaces {
                vlan.16 {
                    host-inbound-traffic {
                        system-services {
                            dhcp;
                            all;
                        }
                    }
                }
                fe-0/0/5.0;
            }
        }
        security-zone untrust {
            interfaces {
                pp0.0 {
                    host-inbound-traffic {
                        system-services {
                            ssh;
                            ping;
                            traceroute;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
vlans {
    vlan-trust {
        vlan-id 16;
        l3-interface vlan.16;
    }
}
```

When I run ping to anything from the Juniper itself, sometimes the ping is fine but at some points I'm getting PL as well.  Even to my GW.  If I switch back to Cisco ASA 5505 -- I'm getting literally no PL.

Does anyone have any suggestions what to look at?  I tried different ports, wipe out config and try again etc. nothing helps.  Given the other protocols work fine during the PL on ICMP / traceroute I suspect some kind of limiting kicking in, but how to find which one it is???  I'm pretty sure I disabled all screens etc...

Any advice, much appreciated.

EDIT: I'm running latest recommended software version -- 12.1X44-D40.2

```
root> show version
Model: srx210be
JUNOS Software Release [12.1X44-D40.2]
```

EDIT 2: I just made a test; I connected a Raspberry PI directly to the interface and started MTRing that.  Below is the result:

```
                                            Packets               Pings
 Host                                     Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. 10.17.17.62                           47.3%   112    1.2   1.2   1.0   3.3   0.3
 2. 10.50.50.2                             0.0%   111    1.7   1.9   1.3  14.4   1.7
```

With 10.17.17.62 being the GW again.

After further tests, it seems like ICMP is not actually affected.  It's just MTR which is using UDP for traceroute.  However, I can't really track down what the hell is limiting / dropping that.

Comment: how did you receive such a result table ? mine traceroute/ping results look much alike the usual UNIX ones.

Comment: it's from mtr -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software).  I was really (positively) surprised to see it's now a part of standard Junos software

Comment: which junos version do you run on it ?

Comment: ah sorry, didn't mention it -- 12.1X44-D40.2 so latest recommended by JTAC

Comment: does packet loss manifest itself by some ways other than mtr ran from srx console ?

Comment: no not really.  it's mainly traceroute UDP packets that are intermittently being lost.  no other TCP / UDP traffic is being lost :/

Comment: then probably it's the mtr itself that doesn't work properly. conduct some tests from a device behind SRX.

Comment: nah I wouldn't suspect mtr itself.  traceroute and ICMP manifests similar behaviour it's just more difficult to catch the using mtr.  Thanks for following up, anyway